# I can't insert a new movie into the array of 10 correctly

Tags: c++, arrays

can someone tell me what is wrong with my InsertMovie()? and help me with solution to it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Movie.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#ifndef _Movie_
#define _Movie_
#include <iostream>

struct Movie
{
    std::string title;
    int criticRating; // from 0 to 100
    int audienceRating; // from 0 to 100
};

#endif /*defined _Movie_*/

void PrintMovies(Movie*, int);
void SortMoviesByAudienceRating(Movie*, int);
void InsertMovie(Movie*, int, const Movie&);

int main()
{
    //auto automatically assumes what type
    //constexpr = static const int
    constexpr auto NumMovies = 10;
    Movie* movie = new Movie[NumMovies];
    movie[0] = {   "Kung Fu Panda 3", 81, 86};
    movie[1] = {   "Hail, Caesar", 81, 46};
    movie[2] = {   "Star Wars VII - The Force Awakens", 92, 90};
    movie[3] = {   "The Revenant", 82, 85};
    movie[4] = {   "The Choice", 7, 67};
    movie[5] = {   "Pride and Prejudice and Zombies", 45, 59};
    movie[6] = {   "The Finest Hours", 59, 72};
    movie[7] = {   "Ride Along 2", 13, 55};
    movie[8] = {   "The Boy", 31, 45};
    movie[9] = {   "Dirty Grandpa", 9, 51};

    PrintMovies(movie, NumMovies);
    SortMoviesByAudienceRating(movie, NumMovies);
    PrintMovies(movie, NumMovies);

    Movie newMovie = { "The Jungle Book", 84, 80 };

    InsertMovie(movie, NumMovies, newMovie);
    PrintMovies(movie, NumMovies);

    return 0;
}

void InsertMovie(Movie* movies, int numMovies, const Movie& movie)
{
    Movie temp1, temp2;

    for (int i = 0; i < numMovies; ++i)
    {
        if (movie.audienceRating >= movies[i].audienceRating)
        {
            for (int j = numMovies - 1; j > numMovies - i + 1; --j)
            {
                movies[j] = movies[j - 1];
            }

            temp1 = movies[i];
            movies[i] = movie;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is this:

//before InsertMovie()

```
Movies:
Critic    Audience    Title
------------------------------
 92        90        Star Wars VII - The Force Awakens
 81        86        Kung Fu Panda 3
 82        85        The Revenant
 59        72        The Finest Hours
 7         67        The Choice
 45        59        Pride and Prejudice and Zombies
 13        55        Ride Along 2
 9         51        Dirty Grandpa
 81        46        Hail, Caesar
 31        45        The Boy
```

//After InsertMovie()

```
Movies:
Critic  Audience   Title
------------------------------
 92     90        Star Wars VII - The Force Awakens
 81     86        Kung Fu Panda 3
 82     85        The Revenant
 84     80        The Jungle Book
 7      67        The Choice
 45     59        Pride and Prejudice and Zombies
 13     55        Ride Along 2
 9      51        Dirty Grandpa
 81     46        Hail, Caesar
 81     46        Hail, Caesar
```

Comment: Using a `std::list<Movie>` (or even a `std::map<int, Movie>`) instead of a `Movie[]` would solve all your troubles and make your code smaller, less error prone, more readable, and a hot cup of coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

First your not counting backwards correctly when you try to push away the items foolwing the item i.  Try:

```
        for (int j = numMovies - 1; j > i ; --j)
        {
            movies[j] = movies[j - 1];
        }
```

Second, I don't know if it's on purpose or not, you don't increase the size of your array.  This means that there will always be only 10 movies in the array.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/inbK7d)

Comment: Yeah I only want the the size of the array to stay at 10

Comment: But anyways wow! thank you very much. Your solution did exactly the trick!! I'm very grateful